# Naming a return variable

Tags: r, return, user-defined-functions

All the examples I see of user-defined functions finish with `return(result)` or the like — but always with some generic variable name.

It seems to me, though, that it would be helpful to name the result something unique. In my understanding functions exist so that you can reuse them often, so it would be helpful to have a non-generic name.

EDIT: I realize that the best way to name the result is to save it to a variable when you call it. I am more asking about when I want to return more than one value. Specifically I want to return two separate data frames (and ideally a plot based on them but I am willing to make a separate function for that). I know I can make a separate function but it would be much more efficient for me if one function could create two dataframes.

Comment: Not sure I clearly understand your question, but you can write `unique_name <- function()` to store output of `function()`. According to your edit, your function can return a list of data.frames.

Comment: Assuming that you want a multi-argument return with names you can use to access components: you could return a list with names, like this: `res <- list(df1=df1,df2=df2,my_plot=plot); return(res)`

Comment: In addition to the previous comments: To access your results (after following the hints), access your results like this: unique_name$df1, .. unique_name$my_plot

Comment: Thanks all. That's what I need. But still Is there a way to use a character string to name a dataframe? I am thinking of the rename function, but for renaming entire dataframes. If I have character string "abcd" is there any way I can command R to use that string to name a df?